# How to find a line corresponding to the step in the body?

Tags: r, debugging

Let's
take the code as below saved in file "test.R":

```
fun1 <- function() {
c(1,
2,
3)
}
```

Let's say in the file it starts from line 1, i.e. `fun1` definition is
from line 1 to 5. I can now use `utils::findLineNum("test.R", line = 3)[[1]]$at` to get the location in the body, but how to get a line
having the location in the body?

Full code:

```
fun1 <- function() {
  c(1,
    2,
    3)
}

at <- utils::findLineNum("test.R", line = 3)[[1]]$at

getSrcLocation(body(fun1)[[at]], "line") # returns NULL :(
```

Is there some specific function for this? The problem is that in the
example above, the `at` points to the line 2, not 3 if I can say that
(we can check this using `utils::findLineNum("test.R", line = 2)[[1]]$at`: returned value is the same as for line 3) and **I need to get this
first line to which the `at` refers to**.

```
fun1 <- function() {
  c(1,
    2,
    3)
}

at <- utils::findLineNum("test.R", line = 3)[[1]]$at

body(fun1)[[at]] <- "In which line am I assuming function starts from line 1?"

body(fun1)
```

Above, `at` determines the part of the body which will be replaced by string and this string will be in line 2. How to get this information that it will be line 2?

---

At first I thought I could do something similar as @Allan Cameron said in the answer, I mean "see when 'at' has changed' (using `identical()`, but then I got this example:

```
fun1 <- function() {
    reactable::reactable(src_data,
                         columns = list(col = reactable::colDef(cell = function(value) {
                                                                       if (TRUE) {
                                                                         my_fun(value)
                                                                       } else {
                                                                         value
                                                                       }
                                                                     }
                                        )),
                         highlight = TRUE)
}
```

And the line of interest was the line with `highlight = TRUE)`, so the line 11 (counting from 1) and my solution didn't work because of this nested `if else` (@Allan Cameron proposition do not work as well because of some error). Then I thought I could use `sum()` instead of `identical()` to check when the sum starts to be lower. But the problem is - is the code below reliable?:

```
fun1 <- function() {
    reactable::reactable(src_data,
                         columns = list(col = reactable::colDef(cell = function(value) {
                                                                       if (TRUE) {
                                                                         my_fun(value)
                                                                       } else {
                                                                         value
                                                                       }
                                                                     }
                                        )),
                         highlight = TRUE)
}

determine_line <- function(file, line, object_envir_orig, object_at_orig) {
  still_lines_to_check <- TRUE
  while (still_lines_to_check) {
    line <- line - 1
    obj <- utils::findLineNum(file, line, nameonly = FALSE, envir = object_envir_orig, lastenv = object_envir_orig)
    if (length(obj) > 0) {
      obj <- obj[[length(obj)]]
      at <- obj$at
      if (sum(at) < sum(object_at_orig)) {
        line <- line + 1
        still_lines_to_check <- FALSE
      }
    } else {
      still_lines_to_check <- FALSE
    }
  }
  line
}

determine_line("file.R", 11, environment(fun1), findLineNum("file.R", 11)[[1]]$at)
```

And also - I was hoping to have something faster than `determine_line()`.

Comment: Are you looking for `getSrcLines(srcfile("test.R"), 3, 3)`?

Comment: @Rui Barradas, I have edited my question to be (perhaps) more precise. Thank you, but no, I need something which returns the line number.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to backtrack through the lines until the `at` changes, which means you are no longer within the same step of the function. Keep track of the line as you do this. The following function gives an example of how this might work, along with forward tracking to tell you where the step ends. This can be simplified as needed. Note it does not require first sourcing the file, since it is done within the function.

```r
locate_body_line <- function(file, line_num) {
  source(file, local = TRUE)
  line_info <- findLineNum(file, line = line_num)[[1]]
  at <- line_info$at[1]
  
  f <- get(line_info$name)
  
  starts <- at
  ends   <- at
  myline <- line_num
  
  while(starts == at) {
    myline <- myline - 1
    ln <- findLineNum(file, line = myline)[[1]]
    starts <-  ln$at
  }

  starts <- myline + 1
  myline <- line_num
  
  while(ends == at) {
    myline <- myline + 1
    ln <- findLineNum(file, line = myline)
    if(length(ln) == 0) break
    ends <-  ln[[1]]$at
  }
  ends <- myline - 1

  cat("Line ", line_num, " of file '", file, 
      "' is within the function \"", line_info$name, "\"\n", sep = "")
  cat("\nThe line includes the step:\n", deparse(body(f)[[at]]),
      "\nwhich starts on line", starts, "and ends on line", ends)
}
```

```
locate_body_line("../test.R", line = 3)
#> Line 3 of file '../test.R' is within the function "fun1"
#> 
#> The line includes the step:
#>  c(1, 2, 3) 
#> which starts on line 2 and ends on line 4
```

Comment: Thank you, I have marked this answer as useful, but it doesn't work in my real example (I should post this before) - I'm editing my question to include my real example and my proposition. I'm not sure, however, if my proposition is reliable and will work with any example I can imagine.